# HTML5 cache manifest exception

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser-cache, application-cache

I tried to use the applicationcach on my site, but I have a big problem with it. I want to cache only 3 files: `style.css` `favicon.ico` and `script.js`.

The problem is, that the browser stores the other files also (eg. index.php)

The code is:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

FALLBACK:
/ /offline.php

NETWORK:
*

CACHE:
style.css
favicon.ico
script.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will always cache the file that the manifest is referenced from.  If you're referencing your manifest from your `index.php` file then that file will be cached.  You may be able to include a static file in an `iframe` with a reference to the manifest so you don't have to include it in all your pages.